# Is it possible for there to exist metastable exotic atoms?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, exotic-matter, nuclear-isomers

I've been quite fascinated with the invention and discovery of exotic atoms such as: [positronium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium), and muonic hydrogen etc...

Now I know positronium has a longer than usual lifetime because it is in a metastable state. My question is a rather laymans question but how metastable can these exotic atoms get? Could you end up with a scenario similar to tantalum 180m which is effectively stable due to the enormous transition required?

Comment: Possibly useful idea: for muonic atoms, the lifetime is driven by the lifetime of their unstable constituents (=muons). While we can make neutron "stable" by binding it into nuclei, this does not work for muons, because (1) muons are not composite, and (2) m(mu)-m(e) is much larger than m(n)-m(p).